# How Can I Speed Up Multiple Requests In node.js?

Tags: node.js, request, monitoring, ping, monitor

I have a code which is basically checks a bunch of websites if they are up or down.

```
const request = require('request');
const urls = [];

var start = Date.now();
var count = 1;
var countUrls = urls.length;

var up= 0
var down = 0;

function callback(start) {
    console.log((Date.now() - start) + 'ms execution.');
    console.log('\n Up: ' + up + ' Down: ' + down);
    process.exit()
}

urls.forEach( function(url) {
    var options = {
    url: url,
    timeout: 10000
    };

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if(error) {
            console.error(count + ': ' + url + ' is down: ' + error);
            count++;
            down++;
        } else {
            console.log(count + ': ' + url + ' is up: ');
            count++;
            up++;
        }

        if((count - 1) == countUrls) {
            callback(start);
        }
    });
});
```

It works just fine. In my urls array I have 120 URLs. When I run this code it executes itself in like 20-30 seconds. But if I increase the number o URLs to 720, the execution time increases to 1 minutes and 30 second.

I want to understand 2 things;

1- The timeout is set to 10 seconds. How can it goes beyond that even with 120 URLs?

2- This code is not requires a good hardware, it is just connecting to the websites. What can I do to speed this up? I want check really huge number of URLs (maybe 100k) under 1 minute because my code will run every minute.

FYI, this code is running in my local machine and I have an 24 MBPS internet connection. This could be the problem but most of the servers has 1 GBPS internet connection and when I compare 24 - 1 and 120 - 100k it makes me tought it would not be enough.

Comment: you should try this using Promises that way u can make it work better

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Promise.all() which will launch all of the requests in parallel (as opposed to sequential which is what you are currently doing).

```
Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
});
```

where each of these elements of the array correspond to the URL (or request at least) to your websites.

You may have problems launching 100,000 requests in parallel - but then just code around that.

You will naturally need to consider error handling in case one of them fails, but in short this is what you need to be looking at.